# Main variable not updating when I modify it in function

Tags: python

Could anyone give me some assistance with the following code? Everything is fine except one minor error. Basically, the code asks the user for a word. The word is taken and then masked. For example, let's say I enter the word: football

football is then converted to ******** (one * for each letter). After that, the code will ask the user for a number of guesses to attempt. Let's say I enter 8 (exactly how long the word football is).

After 8 is entered, the user will be asked to give a guess 8 times, with each correct guess updating the masked string to show the guessed letter. The problem is that I want the program to automatically end right after the word has been revealed. For example, with football, each time a duplicate letter (ex. o and l) is entered, two letters are revealed and a guess attempt is skipped. So after football is entirely unmasked, the code/program still asks for 2 additional guesses. I don't want these two additional guesses, I want the program to end immediately. But I can't figure out how to do it.

I tried to set the following command at the end

if masked_secret_word == secret_word:
    break

But that doesn't seem to do anything. I thought it would match the fully guessed word with the original word and then end it but that doesn't seem to work. Anyone able to provide some assistance? Thank you.

```
def word_update (secret_word, guessed_letters):
    masked_secret_word = ""
    for letter_guess in secret_word:
        if letter_guess in guessed_letters:
            masked_secret_word += letter_guess
        else:
            masked_secret_word += "*"
    print "Secret Word update:" + masked_secret_word

alphabet = map(chr, range(97, 123))

secret_word = raw_input ("Type in the secret word: ").lower()
while secret_word.isalpha() == False:
    secret_word = raw_input ("ERROR: Type in the secret word").lower()
masked_secret_word = len(secret_word) * "*"
guesses = raw_input ("How many guesses will you allow?")
while guesses.isdigit() == False or 0 >= int(guesses):
    guesses = raw_input ("ERROR: How many guesses will you allow?")
guesses = int(guesses)
while len(secret_word) > guesses:
    guesses = raw_input ("ERROR: The number of guesses is smaller than the word")
    while guesses.isdigit() == False or 0 >= int(guesses):
        guesses = raw_input ("ERROR: How many guesses will you allow?")
    guesses = int(guesses)
print "Secret Word = " + masked_secret_word
guessed_letters = []
while guesses != 0:
    letter_guess = raw_input ("Guess a letter (a-z)? ")
    while letter_guess not in alphabet:
        letter_guess = raw_input ("ERROR: Guess a letter (a-z)? ")
    if letter_guess in guessed_letters:
        print "That letter has already been guessed."
    else:
        guesses = guesses - 1
        guessed_letters.append(letter_guess)
        word_update(secret_word, guessed_letters)
```

Comment: Please do come up with a better title for your question.

Comment: *Where* did you try to add that one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `word_update()` function only prints, it does not return anything. The `masked_secret_word` variable inside that function is a *local* variable, not visible outside of the function.

Outside of the `word_update()` function, `masked_secret_word` is a different variable with the value `'*******'` so your `secret_word` value will never match it.

Return a value from the function to pass back to the caller:

```
def word_update (secret_word, guessed_letters):
    masked_secret_word = ""
    for letter_guess in secret_word:
        if letter_guess in guessed_letters:
            masked_secret_word += letter_guess
        else:
            masked_secret_word += "*"
    print "Secret Word update:" + masked_secret_word
    return masked_secret_word == secret_word  # returns True or False
```

then test for that return value:

```
if word_update(secret_word, guessed_letters):
    break
```

Comment: Thanks, all of the answers were useful but this one worked the best for me. Thank you, everyone.

Answer (score 3):

In your `word_update()` function, you create a local variable called `masked_secret_word`. That is not the same variable as the `masked_secret_word` in the main code, but a new local variable.

You don't actually ever update the main `masked_secret_word` variable, it remains a series of `'*'`.

The smallest fix for this is to add

```
global masked_secret_word
```

In the `word_update()` function, but a *better* way to do it is to let your `word_update()` function return the new masked_secret_word and use that to update the global variable with a:

```
masked_secret_word = word_update(secret_word, guessed_letters)
```

Then your proposed line would work.

Comment: +1 for explaining the two ways. Kevin, note that most of the time, usage of `global` variable is discouraged, unless you have a good reason to do it. Here, you can do it in a more proper way, so it's better not to use a `global` variable. Your code will be cleaner, easier to understand. Also, note that in python, you can access variables declared in the upper scope ("globally" in your main script) from within a function at any time, without the `global` instruction, in reading only. But as soon you have to write it, you have to declare it as a global like Lennart said.

Answer (score 1):

You are never updating the `masked_secret_word`. You could return it in `word_update()` and then check if it matches the `secret_word`.

Here is the complete code - I added a return statement in the `word_update()` and a check for equality in the main loop:

```
def word_update (secret_word, guessed_letters):
    masked_secret_word = ""
    for letter_guess in secret_word:
        if letter_guess in guessed_letters:
            masked_secret_word += letter_guess
        else:
            masked_secret_word += "*"
    print "Secret Word update:" + masked_secret_word
    return masked_secret_word

alphabet = map(chr, range(97, 123))

secret_word = raw_input ("Type in the secret word: ").lower()
while secret_word.isalpha() == False:
    secret_word = raw_input ("ERROR: Type in the secret word").lower()
masked_secret_word = len(secret_word) * "*"
guesses = raw_input ("How many guesses will you allow?")
while guesses.isdigit() == False or 0 >= int(guesses):
    guesses = raw_input ("ERROR: How many guesses will you allow?")
guesses = int(guesses)
while len(secret_word) > guesses:
    guesses = raw_input ("ERROR: The number of guesses is smaller than the word")
    while guesses.isdigit() == False or 0 >= int(guesses):
        guesses = raw_input ("ERROR: How many guesses will you allow?")
    guesses = int(guesses)
print "Secret Word = " + masked_secret_word
guessed_letters = []
while guesses != 0:
    letter_guess = raw_input ("Guess a letter (a-z)? ")
    while letter_guess not in alphabet:
        letter_guess = raw_input ("ERROR: Guess a letter (a-z)? ")
    if letter_guess in guessed_letters:
        print "That letter has already been guessed."
    else:
        guesses = guesses - 1
        guessed_letters.append(letter_guess)
        masked_secret_word = word_update(secret_word, guessed_letters)
        if masked_secret_word == secret_word:
            # You win
            break
```